# how to structure logic of an excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a tenure calculator to track employee numbers in certain tenure groups as they come and go across the year.
I'm trying to do this through an excel table like the attached picture.
the columns are the start date and end date of the employee,
a column for each of the months e.g. 1/06/2022, 1/07/2022..etc.. for 12 months DD/MM/YYYY format
and the employee name.

So the gist of the logic im struggling with is;
if the start date for the employee is after the current column month date, return 0.
if the end date is not blank (employee still works here) and after the current month(they havent left yet), calculate days between start date and current date (the month date in the header of the table).

no matter what i try it seems to either return 0 regardless, or return 0 as soon as something goes in the end date column.

Any suggestions?

```
=IF([@[Start Date]] >= INDEX(Table1[#Headers], 1, COLUMN()),0,IF(ISBLANK([@[End Date]]),MAX(DAYS(INDEX(Table1[#Headers], 1, COLUMN()), [@[Start Date]]), 0),IF([@[End Date]]<= INDEX(Table1[#Headers], 1, COLUMN()),0, MAX(DAYS(INDEX(Table1[#Headers], 1, COLUMN()), [@[Start Date]]), 0))))
```

This resulted in 0's as soon as i put a date in the end date column
other than that it seems to calculate properly,

[image]

Comment: 01/06/2023,  01/07/2023 - is that 1st Jun, 1st Jul or 6th Jan, 7th Jan?

Comment: DD/MM/YYYY Format, so 1st Jun, 1st Jul etc

Comment: It's quite a challenge. I just simplified the formula using LET: `=LET(s,[@[Start Date]],i,INDEX(Table1[#Headers],1,COLUMN()),e,[@[End Date]],m,MAX(DAYS(i,s),0),IF(s>=i,0,IF(ISBLANK(e),m,IF(e<=i,0,m))))` so it maybe easier for someone to figure it out. It looks like an ingredient is missing.

Comment: The table headers need to be converted to number value in your formula. Headers of tables get converted to text as soon as you turn it into a table structure. So use it like `--INDEX(Table1[#Headers]`.

Comment: If they start and finish in the same month do you want number of days worked in that month?  Thinking something like this might work:  `=LET(StartDate,Table1[@[Start Date]:[Start Date]],EndDate,Table1[@[End Date]:[End Date]],CurrentDate,DATEVALUE(INDEX(Table1[#Headers],,COLUMN())),
          IF(AND(StartDate>=CurrentDate,EndDate<>"",EndDate<=EOMONTH(CurrentDate,0)),EndDate-StartDate,IF(AND(OR(EndDate="",CurrentDate<=EndDate),CurrentDate>=StartDate),CurrentDate-StartDate,0)))`

Comment: Can change `DATEVALUE` to `--`.  Didn't think about that method until @P.b mentioned it.

Comment: Two Questions: (1) Your month columns seem to be **off** by a month. In other words, your column with a header of `1/06/2023` *(i.e. **June**)* is only showing the total through May, and not showing any counts for June. Is that deliberate?  (2) If there is an `End Date`, for the months after the end date, do you want to continue the running total?  Or do you want to show zero's (0) or blanks?

Comment: @Ron, given that the DAYS() function undercounts by one the inclusive number of days between two dates, one interpretation of your observation (1) is that a column header of `01/07/2023` means the number of inclusive days of employment between the start date and **the end of the preceding month**, ie the days between start date and the end of June (counting the length of the period as the number of days between the start start date and 30/06/2023, inclusive). Whether this is what the OP intends only s/he can say definitively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @P.b has very helpfully noted in the comments, the dates in the header row of the table get treated as text and not numbers.

Once this is corrected for some shortening of your formula is possible. In particular, the `MAX` and `DAYS` functions can be dispensed with leaving

```
=IF(
    [@[Start Date]] >= INDEX(--Table1[#Headers], 1, COLUMN()),
    0,
    IF(
        ISBLANK([@[End Date]]),
        INDEX(--Table1[#Headers], 1, COLUMN()) - [@[Start Date]],
        IF(
            [@[End Date]] <= INDEX(--Table1[#Headers], 1, COLUMN()),
            0,
            INDEX(--Table1[#Headers], 1, COLUMN()) - [@[Start Date]]
        )
    )
)
```

Using the `LET` function, again as suggested in the comments (this time by @VBasic2008), might also allow for a bit further of simplification as:

```
=LET(
    start, [@[Start Date]],
    end, [@[End Date]],
    current, INDEX(--Table1[#Headers], 1, COLUMN()),
    IF(
        start >= current,
        0,
        IF(
            ISBLANK(end),
            current - start,
            IF(end <= current, 0, current - start)
        )
    )
)
```

Looking at your table, it seems that its purpose is to calculate the days to date that the employee has been in post. There is a question as to what you wish to show for dates after the employee has left.

The logic you have employed calculates zero for such dates. It is plausible that for these dates you might want to keep the total days of employment, including any additional days of employment in the month of leaving.

If this is the case, change the final `IF` and replace its second argument of `0` with `end - start`, leaving the function as:

```
IF(end <= current, end - start, current - start)
```

**Edit to add**

This changes the full formula to:

```
=LET(
    start, [@[Start Date]],
    end, [@[End Date]],
    current, INDEX(--Table1[#Headers], 1, COLUMN()),
    IF(
        start >= current,
        0,
        IF(
            ISBLANK(end),
            current - start,
            IF(end <= current, end - start, current - start)
        )
    )
)
```

**End of edit**

Finally, a couple of points.

First, both the `DAYS` function and the subtraction of dates that I have used above calculate the number of days on a non-inclusive basis: `DAYS(x,x)` evaluates to zero and not 1. This is worth noting since, in some contexts, if something starts and ends on the same day it might be considered to have a duration of 1 day. To get the inclusive number of days between two dates simply add 1 to the non-inclusive result.

Second, the use of the `COLUMN()` function means that the columns 1,2,3,... of the table must be positioned in worksheet columns 1,2,3,... If you move the table or insert worksheet columns to the left of the table, the formulae in the table may no longer work or calculate what you want.

Comment: I do not think I the get correct answer from your formulas. Try `Start = 19-Jul-2023` and `End = 15-Sep-2023`. Your formula fills in **two** months with a total of `44`. But shouldn't the employee be shown as having worked in **three** months with a total of `59` days?

Comment: @Ron, this is really a question for the OP. The OP's formula utilises a zero for the second argument of the third IF function. This puts a zero for any date (such as 01-Oct-2023) which is after the end date. I have simply followed the OP's logic but the final part of my answer (starting at "Looking at your table, it seems...) does deal with the point you raise. I suggest that to capture the full length of employment the zero in the third IF be changed to `end - start`. This then does show that the total length of employment is `58` days when the end date is set as 15-Sep-2023.

Comment: @Ron I have edited my answer to make the substitution of the `0` by `end - start` clearer.